# A minha lista continua a ter o tail e o head como null

Tags: java, lista, nullpointerexception, null

Estava todo a correr bem até que notei que a lista não é preenchida, deixando o meu head e tail como null. Supostamente o programa devia ler do um ficheiro input e preencher a lista dentro de um ciclo.

Aqui está o código em questão:

```
package projectosalarios;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class Funcionario{
    String Nome;
    String BI;
    int Departamento;
    int Cargo;
    int Salario;
    public Funcionario(String Nome, String BI, int Departamento, int Cargo, int Salario){
        this.Nome = Nome;
        this.BI = BI;
        this.Departamento = Departamento;
        this.Cargo = Cargo;
        this.Salario = Salario;
    }

}

class Lista {
    Node head;
    Node tail;

    public static void add(Lista Lista, Funcionario NovoFuncionario) {
        Node novoNo = new Node (NovoFuncionario);
                if(Lista.head == null){
                    Lista.head = novoNo;
                    Lista.tail = novoNo;
                    }else {
                    novoNo.next = Lista.head;
                Lista.head = novoNo;
        }
    }
}


class Node{
    Funcionario value;
    Node next;
    public Node(Funcionario value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class ProjectoSalarios {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String NomeFicheiro = "C:\\Users\\Nelson\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ProjectoSalarios\\funcionarios.txt";
        String NomeFicheiro2 = "C:\\Users\\Nelson\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ProjectoSalarios\\salarios.txt";

        Lista ListaFuncionario = new Lista();

        int ArraySalario[];
        ArraySalario = new int[15];

        try{
            File Ficheiro2 = new File(NomeFicheiro2);
            try (Scanner leitorFicheiro = new Scanner (Ficheiro2)) {

                while(leitorFicheiro.hasNextLine()){
                    String linha = leitorFicheiro.nextLine();
                    String dados[] = linha.split(":");
                    int Cargo = Integer.parseInt(dados[0]);
                    int Valor = Integer.parseInt(dados[1]);
                    ArraySalario[Cargo-1]= Valor;

                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            String mensagem = "Erro: o ficheiro " + NomeFicheiro2 + " não foi encontrado.";
            System.out.println(mensagem);
        }

        try{
            File Ficheiro = new File(NomeFicheiro);
            Scanner leitorFicheiro = new Scanner(Ficheiro);
            Funcionario NovoFuncionario;
            while(leitorFicheiro.hasNextLine()){
                String Linha = leitorFicheiro.nextLine();
                String dados[] = Linha.split(":");
                String Nome = dados[0];
                String BI = dados[1];
                int Departamento = Integer.parseInt(dados[2]);
                int Cargo = Integer.parseInt(dados[3]);


                NovoFuncionario = new Funcionario(Nome, BI, Departamento, Cargo, ArraySalario[Cargo-1]); 
                Lista.add(ListaFuncionario, NovoFuncionario);
            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            String mensagem = "Erro: o ficheiro " + NomeFicheiro + " não foi encontrado.";
            System.out.println(mensagem);
        }

        try (BufferedWriter Writer = new BufferedWriter ( new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Nelson\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ProjectoSalarios\\output.txt"))) {
            Writer.write(ProcurarSalario(ListaFuncionario, "12312355"));
            Writer.write(SomaSalario(ListaFuncionario, 1));
            Writer.write(SomaSalarioCargo(ListaFuncionario, 1));
            Writer.write(SalarioAlto(ListaFuncionario, 1000));
            Writer.write(SalarioAltoPessoas(ListaFuncionario, 1000));
            Writer.write(SalarioBaixo(ListaFuncionario, 1000));
            Writer.write(SalarioBaixoPessoas(ListaFuncionario, 1000));
            Writer.write(SalarioAltoDepartamento(ListaFuncionario, 1));
            Writer.write(SalarioBaixoDepartamento(ListaFuncionario, 1));
            Writer.write(Duplicados(ListaFuncionario, "12312355"));
        }

    }

    static int ProcurarSalario(Lista Lista, String BI){ //1
        Node Copy = Lista.head;
        while(Copy!=null){
            if(Copy.value.BI.equals(BI)){
                return Copy.value.Salario;
            }
   Copy = Copy.next;
        }return 0;
    }

    static int SomaSalario(Lista Lista, int Departamento){ //2
        Node Copy = Lista.head;
        int Sum= 0;
        while(Copy !=null){
            if(Copy.value.Departamento == 10){
                Sum+=Copy.value.Salario;
            }
            Copy = Copy.next;
        }return Sum;
    }

    static int SomaSalarioCargo(Lista Lista, int Cargo){ //3
        Node Copy = Lista.head;
        int Sum = 0;
        while (Copy !=null){
            if(Copy.value.Cargo == 3){
                Sum+=Copy.value.Salario;
            }
            Copy = Copy.next;
        }return Sum;
    }

    static int SalarioAlto(Lista Lista, int Salario){ //4
        Node Copy = Lista.head;
        while(Copy !=null && Copy.next != null){ //CHECK HERE
            if(Copy.value.Salario < Copy.next.value.Salario ){
                Copy = Copy.next;
            }else{
                Copy.next = Copy.next.next;
            }
        }return Copy.value.Salario;
    }

    static int SalarioAltoPessoas(Lista Lista, int Salario){ //5
        Node Copy = Lista.head;
        int i = 1;
        while(Copy !=null && Copy.next != null){ //CHECK HERE
            if(Copy.value.Salario < Copy.next.value.Salario ){
                Copy = Copy.next;
                i=1;
            }else if(Copy.value.Salario > Copy.next.value.Salario){
                Copy.next = Copy.next.next;
            }else{
                i++;
                Copy.next = Copy.next.next;
            }
        }return i;
    }

    static int SalarioBaixo(Lista Lista, int Salario){ //6
        Node Copy = Lista.head;
        while(Copy !=null && Copy.next != null){ //CHECK HERE
            if(Copy.value.Salario > Copy.next.value.Salario ){
                Copy = Copy.next;
            }else{
                Copy.next = Copy.next.next;
            }
        }return Copy.value.Salario;
    }



    static int SalarioBaixoPessoas(Lista Lista, int Salario){ //7
        Node Copy = Lista.head;
        int i = 1;
        while(Copy !=null && Copy.next != null){ //CHECK HERE
            if(Copy.value.Salario > Copy.next.value.Salario ){
                Copy = Copy.next;
                i=1;
            }else if(Copy.value.Salario < Copy.next.value.Salario){
                Copy.next = Copy.next.next;
            }else{
                i++;
                Copy.next = Copy.next.next;
            }
        }return i;
    }

    static int SalarioAltoDepartamento(Lista Lista, int Departamento){ //8
        Node Copy = Lista.head;
        int departamento [] = new int [10];
        while(Copy!=null){
            departamento[Copy.value.Departamento-1] += Copy.value.Salario;
            Copy=Copy.next;
        }
        int Maximo=departamento[0];
        int Codigo=0;
        for(int i : departamento) {
            if(departamento [i] > Maximo){
                Maximo = departamento[i];
                Codigo=i+1;
            }
        }return Codigo;
    }

    static int SalarioBaixoDepartamento(Lista Lista, int Departamento){ //9
        Node Copy = Lista.head;
        int departamento [] = new int [10];
        while(Copy!=null){
            departamento[Copy.value.Departamento-1] += Copy.value.Salario;
            Copy=Copy.next;
        }

        int f=0;
        if(departamento[f] == 0){
            f++;
        }
        int Minimo = departamento[f];
        int Codigo=0;
        for(int i : departamento) {
            if(departamento [i] <= Minimo && departamento [i] != 0){
                Minimo = departamento[i];
                Codigo=i+1;
            }
        }return Codigo;
    }

    static String Duplicados(Lista Lista, String BI){
        Node Copy = Lista.head;
        String Escrita =BI;
        while(Copy!=null){
            if(!Copy.value.BI.equals(BI)){
                Copy = Copy.next;
            }else{
                Escrita += ";" + Copy.value.Nome ;
                Copy = Copy.next;
                }
            if(Escrita.equals(BI)){
                Escrita = "Nenhum";
            }
        }return Escrita;
    }





}
```

Os ficheiros possuem a seguinte informação:

**funcionarios.txt:**

```
Victor Valente:12312355:1:1
João Neves:12312777:10:1
Ivo Leite:12343119:10:2
Osvaldo Pires:12312765:2:1
Tiago Santos:12302050:2:2
Joana Cegripe:12999121:2:3
João Almeida:12340050:5:3
Rui Sebastião:12319101:10:3
Miguel Patrocínio:14233000:3:2
Raquel Cunhada:14244111:2:7
Luís Prima:12319101:1:1
```

**salarios.txt**

```
1:1000
2:1050
3:1200
4:1080
5:1700
6:1081
7:1700
8:1010
9:1910
10:890
```

Também adiciono que o debug só me aponta como a minha lista nao foi preenchida.

*Edit:
Codigo atualizado e continua a não preencher a lista, head e tail continuam null.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, seja bem vindo.

Como é um trabalho de universidade vou me manter em algumas dicas apenas:

1) Ficheiro2 é percorrido, mas não é adicionado a sua lista.

2) Ficheiro então é tentado, mas sem fechar o ficheiro2, é possível que está caindo no catch e nem abrindo ele.

3) Coloque mais System.out.println(mensagem) pelo seu código quando chegar em um problema assim, vai te ajudar a entender o problema. Saber por onde está passando e o valor das variáveis para saber o que está funcionando e onde está falhando. Ou use o próprio debugger da aplicação, mas é importante saber se está entrando no catch e nem abrindo os arquivos, por exemplo, para te ajudar a resolver o problema.

Bom trabalho,

Comment: Uma resposta ao Rodrigo, o "Ficheiro2" é suposto não ser adicionado à lista, este é um ficheiro separado para criar um array de salarios para uma adição mais simples à lista mais tarde usando a classe "Funcionario". Quando ao seu segundo ponto, eu estava a pensar nisso para ser sincero mas o meu parceiro de codigo tentou fazer isso mas correu-lhe mal por isso, eu deveria tentar fechar o "Ficheiro2" e depois abrir o "Ficheiro" para ver como correr. Também agradeço a dica do final. :)

Comment: Informo que mesmo com as alterações a lista continua a não ser feita, o head e tail continuam como null.